# Can Apache BeanUtils be used to REMOVE items from a list instead of setting them to null?

Tags: java, apache-commons-beanutils

I am considering using Apache BeanUtils to manage some data structures in my project. The task is for an arbitrary path, known only at runtime, to *remove* items from a list.

I think I can use BeanUtils to set an item to null with a call like this:

```
PropertyUtils.setProperty(myObject, "subitem.aList[3]", null);
```

However in other areas of my project there are loops which iterate over these lists. Having a null item in the list is currently unhandled. There are many (dozens, possibly hundreds) places where the code expects these items to not be null so it is unfortunately impractical to add a null check to all of the code that might iterate over these lists.

Is it possible to use `BeanUtils` to remove an item from a collection instead of setting it to null?

I think I can implement this myself by parsing the path passed to `setProperty` and determining if its a `List` by looking for paths ending with `[<number>]` then parsing out the number, getting the `List` with the path to the list and calling `remove(number)`. I would like to use existing solutions before rolling my own.

Comment: I doubt you can remove attributes using `PropertyUtil` as it is primarily mean to retrieve/update the property values of a bean. If you are worried about `NullPointer`, can you set `Empty List` as `PropertyUtils.setProperty(myObject, "subitem.aList[3]", new ArrayList());`?

Comment: I don't want to remove the entire list, I want to remove a single item from the list.

Comment: I thought `subitem.aList[3]` is a list. I guest this is what I would retrieve the list, remove the item and set it back. Please look at the answer for sample code pattern.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can achieve your results with two steps process as below:

```
    List aList = (List)PropertyUtils.getProperty(myObject, "subitem.aList");
    aList.remove(3); // remove the fourth element

    //set the modified list back
    PropertyUtils.setProperty(myObject, "subitem.aList", aList);
```